# how to set OutputFormat.simple to OutputFormat.detailed using objective-c in microsoft cognitive speech lib?

Tags: objective-c, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-speech-platform

reference|https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/objectivec/cognitive-services/speech/spxspeechconfiguration

Currently in `spxspeechconfiguration` objective-c doesn't contain any method like `setOutputFormat` which allow us to set it `OutputFormat.detailed`.

I need to get the detailed information, since currently the default of spxspeechconfiguration `OutputFormat` is `OutputFormat.simple`.

**I saw at Java for android, it has this method**
reference|https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechconfig.setoutputformat?view=azure-java-stable#com_microsoft_cognitiveservices_speech_SpeechConfig_setOutputFormat_OutputFormat_

as you can see on the reference for java-android method, it has `setOutputFormat()`, but objective-c not.

How can I set it up to `OutputFormat.detailed` using the objective-c? please kindly guide me, thank you.

Comment: `/**
      * The requested Cognitive Services Speech Service response output format (simple or detailed). Not implemented yet.
      */`

Answer (score 0):

`SPXSpeechConfiguration *speechConfig = [[SPXSpeechConfiguration alloc] initWithSubscription:speechKey region:serviceRegion];`

`[speechConfig setPropertyTo:@"True" byId:SPXSpeechServiceResponseRequestDetailedResultTrueFalse];`

*After trial and error, apparently `SPXSpeechServiceResponseRequestDetailedResultTrueFalse` is already implemented since it returning the detail after set the property to `True`. maybe documentation should change the method comment that `its already implemented` with some steps how to set it up, instead of `not implemented yet`.*